# What does it mean for two random variables to be equal?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm working through Apendix A of Bickel and Doksum's Mathematical Statistics, and I'm having trouble understanding the following. They say two random variables are considered equal when the probability of $(X\ne Y)$ is zero. Obviously if $X$ and $Y$ are equal as functions, this holds true. However, is there any scenario in which they would be equal under the definition, but not as functions? Should we distinguish between these two senses of 'equal'?

Also, is the probability of two jointly distributed continuous variables being equal always zero? Since you're integrating over $ D = {(x,x): x \in \mathbb{R}} $?

Comment: Note that "probability $0$" is not the same as "impossible" , hence it would be better to name it "almost surely equal" , unless we are in the discrete case.

Comment: Yes but is this the same as the random variables considered as functions being equal?

Comment: @othi You need to be careful if you think of functions as functions in the literal sense or equivalence classes of functions in the Lebesgue sense. For example the characteristic function of a singleton is considered as equal to $0$ in the Lebesgue sense (usually one calls this _equal almost everywhere_.)

Comment: That's the trouble, I don't have any understanding of measure theory so I'm trying to understand this without reference to that. I'm doing a course in Mathematical Statistics and simply don't have time to get into measure theory. So Ijust want to know: are the functions the same in the LITERAL sense if  the event described above has probability zero?

Comment: No. And, possibly unpopular opinion, probability is nothing else than measure theory restricted to finite measures and cumbersome notation (your mileage may vary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw $\omega$ uniformly from $[0,1]$. Let $X$ be the random variable that is $1$ if  $\omega>1/2$ and $0$ otherwise. Let $Y$ the random variable that is $1$ if $\omega\geq 1/2$. Then $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ as long as $\omega\neq 1/2$. Thus $X$ and $Y$ are not equal as functions, but the set where they differ is of probability $0$ (since $P(\omega=1/2)=0$ in this example), so they are equal as random variables.

What you said about jointly distributed **continuous** random variables is also true.

Comment: Why is this set of probability zero?

Comment: When you draw $\omega$ uniformly from an interval, the probability of getting any specific point is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be any probability space in which there exists a nonempty event $A\in\mathcal{F}$ with $P(A)=0$. Let $X$ be any random variable on that space, and define $Y:=X+I_A$, where $I_A$ is the indicator function for $A$. Then $P(X\neq Y)=0$, but $X$ and $Y$ are not the same function.